# Measuring react components mount times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-performance

I'm trying to find a way to measure the time certain components take to mount, taking into consideration than the library for measuring is asynchronous ([firebase-performance](/questions/tagged/firebase-performance)) to be specific.

I need to find out how long a page consisting of multiple asynchronously mounted components takes to render. I am not sure, how I should go about tracking the time between the time component is invoked (function) and the time it takes to mount (render).

I'm slightly confused by the life-cycle methods, as [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) is considered deprecated. Basically, my understanding would be, that in order to track the time component takes to render would be the following.

```js
class Example extends Component<Props> {
   async componentDidMount() {
      // let's just say this takes 3 seconds as an external API call
      await exampleCall()
   }

   render() {
     return <h1>Test</h1>
   }
}
```

And in order to measure the performance of this component in a easily reproducable way, I wanted to construct a wrapper for the component

```js
import perf from '@react-native-firebase/perf'

const withPerformance = (PassedComponent) => {
  class Tracker extends Component<Props> {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log('constructor fired')
        this.trace = null
     }

     async componentWillMount() {
        const trace = await perf.stratTrace('perf_test')
        console.log('Started perf tracking')
        this.trace = trace
     }

     async componentDidMount() {
        if (this.trace) {
          console.log('Stopped tracking perf')
          await this.trace.stop()
        } else {
          console.log('Mounted, but tracking did not instantiate')
        }
     }

     render() {
        return <PassedComponent {...this.props} />
     }
  }

  return Tracker
}
```

So in order for my perf tracking needs, I could just wrap my existing components with the following wrapper

```js
// last line of Example.js:
export default withPerformance(Example)
```

This however results, when opening the remote debugger in my simulator with very confusingly:

> constructor fired `[constructor]`
> Mounted, but tracking did not instantiate `[componentDidMount]`
> Started perf tracking `[componentWillMount]`

And my firebase console is empty with no custom traces.
This is confusing and wrong for multiple reasons, but the worst culprit is obviously the breaking of the flow of the lifecycle methods, which should be as follows:

> [image]

But in my case, it seems to be `constructor` -> `CDM` -> `CWM`

1. This seems to seemingly break the component lifecycle as `componentWillMount` somehow fires after `componentDidMount` (albeit this might be due to the asynchronous nature), which is not ideal to begin with.
2. `componentWillMount` is a deprecated lifecycle method to begin with, but there seems to be no replacement for it introduced where I could begin any asynchronous subscriptions before the actual DOM nodes are loaded.
3. I am forced to use asynchronity in the lifecycle methods, which is not ideal to begin with.
4. As of note, I am aware of the `Profiler` introduced in react, but I need this to be able to work in production as well, which right now is not recommended with the Profiler.

Any idea how I should go about doing this?
I did experiment with manual tracking with `performance.now()` which does work, but it's a client requirement *(not in an architectural, but actual client sense)* does want the integration to work with the firebase performance tracking.